# sql how many days one period of time has in another period of time

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql

I have two parameters:

```sql
@startDate date = N'2022-01-17'
@endDate date = N'2022-02-28'
```

And a table with data (not related to parameters)

| jobnr | startdate | duedate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| nr324 | 2022-01-09 | 2022-01-19 |
| nr326 | 2022-04-09 | 2022-05-13 |

The task is to calculate how many days of my parameters happens in every month between table dates, and group them by months of parameters ((jan,february))

Output should be something like this:

```
| JobNr  | Month      | How many days  |
|:-------|:----------:| --------------:|
| nr324  | January    |3               |              
| nr324  | February   |0               |
| nr326  | January    |0               |             
| nr326  | February   |0               |
```

** 3 is because 17.01,18.01,19.01 are in selected period for nr324 job
others are zero, because in selected period of @startDate date = N'2022-01-17' @endDate date = N'2022-02-28' nothing happened.**

I can't quite get it around my head. I understand that somewhere in there should be I think time diff and maybe window function.

Comment: Please share the code which you tried

Comment: FYI, "simple" things like spelling your words in full (not using txt spk) and capitalising the start of your sentences goes a long way. If you put a *little* effort into the spelling and grammar of your post, then those you are asking for help from and far more liekly to put effort back in to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Could there ever be data spanning more than 12 months in `[And a table with data]`? Would the results make sense when you can't tell April from April in different years? Or would you just combine all of the months with rhyming names into one row?

Comment: No, if period in parameters more then a year, then it will be new set of columns with year, no combining by it. But it is a large table with a lot of info on jobs, and usually it wont even load if period more that 6months...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track with the months CTE, but you need to be careful of end conditions such as for the range 2022-01-31 to 2022-02-01.  From there you can `CROSS JOIN` the calendar with your job data to calculate the number of overlapping dates between the job, month, and overall range.

SQL Server doesn't have a LEAST() or GREATEST() function to operate on discrete values, so another method is needed, For two values, a simple CASE statement may be used, but for comparing 3 or more values, that logic gets increasingly complex. A trick to keep things relatively simple is to use the MIN() and MAX() aggregate functions operating on a set of data defined using VALUES syntax.

From there, you can calculate the number of days, with care to avoid negative ranges.

The end result is something like:

```
;WITH Months (Date) AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(@startdate), @startdate) -- First-of-month
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, Date)
    from months
    where DATEADD(month, 1, Date) <= @enddate -- Inclusive
)
SELECT
    JobNr = D.jobnr,
    Month = DATENAME(month, M.Date),
    [How Many Days] = CASE
        WHEN R.RangeStart <= R.RangeEnd
        THEN 1 + DATEDIFF(DAY, R.RangeStart, R.RangeEnd)
        ELSE 0
        END
FROM Months M
CROSS JOIN @Data D
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT RangeStart = MAX(StartDate), RangeEnd = MIN(EndDate)
    FROM (
        VALUES
            (@startDate, @endDate),
            (M.Date, EOMONTH(m.Date)),
            (D.startdate, D.duedate)
    ) A(StartDate, EndDate)
) R
ORDER BY D.jobnr, M.Date
```

End dates (@endDate and duedate) are assumed to all be inclusive. The above logic will also work for ranges spanning multiple years, you would likely want to add `YEAR(M.Date)` to the results.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=76c6df97f03505709777a39486ea522a) for a demo.

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what I needed. And it looks pretty hard, yeah... now to implement it into heavily grouped procedure, good luck me. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @a table (
   jobnr     VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL 
  ,startdate DATE  NOT NULL
  ,duedate   DATE  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @a(jobnr,startdate,duedate) VALUES 
('nr324','2022-01-09','2022-01-19'),
('nr326','2022-04-09','2022-05-13');
```

use `join` and `union` and `format` as follows

```
DECLARE @startDate DATE = N'2022-01-17' --yourvariable
DECLARE @endDate DATE = N'2022-02-28' -- yourvariable

SELECT a.month1,
       Count(b.month1) AS 'How many days'
FROM   (SELECT Format(@startDate, 'MMMM') month1---month as name
        UNION
        SELECT Format(@endDate, 'MMMM') month1) a
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT jobnr,
                         startdate,
                         Format(startdate, 'MMMM') month1
                  FROM   @a --your table
                  UNION
                  SELECT jobnr,
                         duedate,
                         Format(duedate, 'MMMM') month1
                  FROM   @a) b
              ON a.month1 = b.month1
GROUP  BY b.month1,
          a.month1
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for help! I am trying to make your code into while loop, because it wont be always two month, it could be one year, or one month, and It should be counted for every job. So I created another table with name of months for this
`create table #calender
([monthname] nvarchar(50)
,daysinmonth int
)
;with months (date)
AS
( SELECT @startdate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, date)
    from months
    where DATEADD(month, 1, date) < @enddate)
insert #calender
select  [MonthName]    = DATENAME(mm, date),
 [DaysInMonth] =  DAY(EOMONTH(date))
from months`

Comment: and trying to do smth like that
'set @x = (select distinct min(RowNr) from #table1)

`while (@x <= (select max(RowNr) from #table1))
BEGIN
SELECT a.month1,
       Count(b.month1) AS 'How many days'
FROM   (SELECT [monthname] as month1 from #calender) a
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT jobnr,
                         startdate,
                         Format(startdate, 'MMMM') month1
                  FROM   #table1) b --your table                 
              ON a.month1 = b.month1
GROUP  BY b.month1,
          a.month1  
  SET @x = @x + 1
   END `
but it working absolutly wrong((

Comment: afterwards you should change the code for alias a

Comment: I use while because i need every job to have this information... I changed how output should look, I was really bad with that, sorry

Comment: anyways, sorry for my bad explaining! Thank you for trying to help!